# react-vertical-timeline-component in Nextjs

Tags: next.js13

I try to use react-vertical-timeline-component lib in Nextjs project. It includes the following dependencies:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@clerk/nextjs": "^4.27.5",
    "@radix-ui/react-dialog": "^1.0.5",
    "@radix-ui/react-menubar": "^1.0.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.10",
    "@tsparticles/engine": "^3.3.0",
    "@tsparticles/react": "^3.0.0",
    "@tsparticles/slim": "^3.3.0",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-tailwindcss": "^3.13.0",
    "framer-motion": "^11.0.8",
    "lucide-react": "^0.295.0",
    "mini-svg-data-uri": "^1.4.4",
    "next": "14.0.3",
    "prettier": "^3.1.0",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-intersection-observer": "^9.8.1",
    "react-vertical-timeline-component": "^3.3.3",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.2.1",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "@types/react-vertical-timeline-component": "^3.3.6",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.0.3",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
```

after I run my app and navigate to the page that has a component with elements from react-vertical-timeline-component I get an error:

Unhandled Runtime Error:

```
Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')

Call Stack
prototype
node_modules\react-vertical-timeline-component\node_modules\react-intersection-observer\react-intersection-observer.m.js (23:48)
_inheritsLoose
node_modules\react-vertical-timeline-component\node_modules\react-intersection-observer\react-intersection-observer.m.js (259:2)
```

Why it happens and how I can fix it?

Comment: pls post stuff like the package.json in the future as code. did you run "npm i" and do you import it in this component? Also you are welcome to post the code from the component where it is used (also as code)

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue myself, and for me it was because I needed to add the "use client" tag at the top of component

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank`s! That is the reason why it doesn`t work!